# Hubspot drop.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: Drop is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am using this library [Drop](https://github.com/HubSpot/drop), but is so poor documented and I can't understand how to use it.
First I have installed:

```
npm install tether-drop
```

I have download Drop.js, and then import it with Tether (import everything):

```
require('../../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min');
require('../../node_modules/tether-drop/dist/js/drop.min');
require('../third_party/drop-master/dist/js/drop.min');
```

, but when I try:

```
let dropInstance = new Drop({
    target: document.querySelector('.dropTarget'),
    content: 'Welcome to the future',
    classes: 'drop-theme-arrows',
    position: 'bottom left',
    openOn: 'click'
});
```

It says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Drop is not defined

I am using Laravel - 5.8 which uses Elixir with GULP (I guess).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I still can't comment but try this way

```
const { Drop } = require('tether-drop');
```

or

```
const Drop = require('tether-drop');
```

depends on how its exported on the module